# Importing JSON data

Tags: importing-exporting

I have Data in JSON format, and I want to insert and update that data into Drupal. I have to update all the records which I got from an external link.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use [drupal_json_decode()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json_decode/7) which is only a one line wrapper to [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) anyway. If you structure your table smartly you can probably just write the output of `json_decode()` straight to the database (if the columns in the table agree with the data); otherwise you will have to manipulate the data a bit.

Answer (score 3):

For the record. A beautiful way to do this is is with Feeds and Feed JSONPath Parser modules. Here is a great article: [Easily import Tweets into Drupal using JSON and Feeds](http://www.bariswanschers.com/blog/easily-import-tweets-drupal-using-json-and-feeds)

Also Data module can be used to import data to custom tables.

Cheers,
Duru.

Comment: Here is another neat example http://www.appnovation.com/blog/consuming-json-feed-using-feeds-and-jsonpath-parser and a great site to work with json data http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would give [JSONData.com](http://www.jsondata.com/) a try. It updates information in real time and can save you a lot of time and work. Hope that helps.

Comment: This looks like a really neat site!  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This link does not work anymore...